# How to create a probability matrix using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my situation.

I have 3 elements assuming their name is

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

For each element, its value could be any value from 0 to 100 with steps 50. which is one of the values from

```
[0, 50, 100]
```

Now I want to create a dataFrame that contains all possibilities for these elements and the dataframe will look like the table below. Here for simplicity, I use 3 elements `['a','b','c']` and 50 as the step in the example but in the real situation there will be much more than 3 elements and the step will be much smaller:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 50 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| 5 | 0 | 50 | 100 |
| 6 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 100 | 50 |
| 8 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| 9 | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 50 | 0 | 50 |
| 11 | 50 | 0 | 100 |
| 12 | 50 | 50 | 0 |
| 13 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| 14 | 50 | 50 | 100 |
| 15 | 50 | 100 | 0 |
| 16 | 50 | 100 | 50 |
| 17 | 50 | 100 | 100 |
| 18 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | 100 | 0 | 50 |
| 20 | 100 | 0 | 100 |
| 21 | 100 | 50 | 0 |
| 22 | 100 | 50 | 50 |
| 23 | 100 | 50 | 100 |
| 24 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| 25 | 100 | 100 | 50 |
| 26 | 100 | 100 | 100 |

How can I create this dataframe efficiently without doing something like for loop inside for loop inside another for loop?

I tried create seperate dataframe like `pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,50,100]})`,then using `pd.merge()` to put them together but it doesn't work like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create all combinations of the wanted values. This can then be added to a dataframe:

```
from  itertools import product

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
vals = [0, 50, 100]

pd.DataFrame(list(product(vals, repeat=len(cols))), columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value_counts()` and divide by number of rows for probability

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[c].value_counts()/len(df)) for c in df.columns], axis=1)
```

#### output

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 |
| 100 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 |
| 50 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 |

Answer (score 0):

As @Shaido suggested you, `itertools.product` is the right choice for your question. You can build dynamically your values with a range depends on the number of columns.

```
import itertools

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
vals = range(0, 50*len(cols), 50)

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(vals, repeat=len(cols), columns=cols)
```

```
>>> df
      a    b    c
0     0    0    0
1     0    0   50
2     0    0  100
3     0   50    0
4     0   50   50
5     0   50  100
6     0  100    0
7     0  100   50
8     0  100  100
9    50    0    0
10   50    0   50
11   50    0  100
12   50   50    0
13   50   50   50
14   50   50  100
15   50  100    0
16   50  100   50
17   50  100  100
18  100    0    0
19  100    0   50
20  100    0  100
21  100   50    0
22  100   50   50
23  100   50  100
24  100  100    0
25  100  100   50
26  100  100  100
```